# Working in IE not in firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

The following code works well in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox.

If someone could suggest the changes, it would be much appreciated.

The code is in the following link

http://www.4shared.com/office/HJNhTiwB/123.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt; 
<head runat="server"> 
<title>MRBN Textbox Sample</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.MRBN 
{ 
    width:145px; 
    font-family:Verdana; 
    font-size:12pt; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #EDEBEC; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function ValidateText(evnt) { 
            TxtLen = document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value.length; 
            document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").style.color = "#33CC33"; 
            if (TxtLen < 5) { 
                if ((((evnt.keyCode > 64) && (evnt.keyCode < 91)) || ((evnt.keyCode > 96) && (evnt.keyCode < 123))) != true) { 
                    alert("1st letter/1st name +1st 4/last name..."); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
            else if (TxtLen == 5) { 
                if (evnt.keyCode != 45) { 
                    alert("This needs dash or hyphen here..."); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
            else if ((TxtLen > 5) && (TxtLen < 11)) { 
                    if (((evnt.keyCode > 47) && (evnt.keyCode < 58)) != true) { 
                        alert("Put last 5 of your phone number..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
            } 
            else { 
                alert("5-5. Now give it to Riders & WIN...!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }

    function ClearText() { 
        if (document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value == "ALPHA-NUMBR") { 
            document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value = ""; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
</script> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <div> 
            <input type="text" id="TxtMRBN" class="MRBN" value="ALPHA-NUMBR" onkeypress="return ValidateText(event);" onmousedown="return ClearText();" /> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Regards

Comment: no ones waiting on 4shared and downloading ur code..use jsfiddle or paste here

Comment: Why do you have text before the `<html>` tag? And what is "works well"; what are the differences? And can you post the resulting HTML (what the browsers see) instead of the original ASP.NET source?

Comment: “Does not work” is not a problem description. The question needs a reformulation, including a descriptive title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code its working in IE,mozilla,chrome

```
    <html>
    <head> 
    <title>MRBN Textbox Sample</title> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .MRBN 
    { 
        width:145px; 
        font-family:Verdana; 
        font-size:12pt; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #EDEBEC; 
    } 
    </style> 
    </head> 
        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            function ValidateText(evnt) { 
         var browserName=navigator.appName; 

       if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
       {
                TxtLen = document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value.length; 
                document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").style.color = "#33CC33"; 
                if (TxtLen < 5) { 
                    if ((((evnt.keyCode > 64) && (evnt.keyCode < 91)) || ((evnt.keyCode > 96) && (evnt.keyCode < 123))) != true) { 
                        alert("1st letter/1st name +1st 4/last name..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if (TxtLen == 5) { 
                    if (evnt.keyCode != 45) { 
                        alert("This needs dash or hyphen here..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if ((TxtLen > 5) && (TxtLen < 11)) { 
                        if (((evnt.keyCode > 47) && (evnt.keyCode < 58)) != true) { 
                            alert("Put last 5 of your phone number..."); 
                            return false; 
                        } 
                } 
                else { 
                    alert("5-5. Now give it to Riders & WIN...!"); 
                    return false; 
                } 
           }
           else  //for firefox and chrome
           {
                 TxtLen = document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value.length; 
                document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").style.color = "#33CC33"; 
                if (TxtLen < 5) { 
                    if ((((evnt.which > 64) && (evnt.which < 91)) || ((evnt.which > 96) && (evnt.which < 123))) != true) { 
                        alert("1st letter/1st name +1st 4/last name..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if (TxtLen == 5) { 
                    if (evnt.which != 45) { 
                        alert("This needs dash or hyphen here..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
                } 
                else if ((TxtLen > 5) && (TxtLen < 11)) { 
                        if (((evnt.which > 47) && (evnt.which < 58)) != true) { 
                            alert("Put last 5 of your phone number..."); 
                            return false; 
                        } 
                } 
                else { 
                    alert("5-5. Now give it to Riders & WIN...!"); 
                    return false; 
                } 
           }
         }

        function ClearText() { 
            if (document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value == "ALPHA-NUMBR") { 
                document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value = ""; 
            } 

        } 
    </script> 
    <body> 

    <form id="form1" > 
            <div> 
                <input type="text" id="TxtMRBN" class="MRBN" value="ALPHA-NUMBR" onkeypress="return ValidateText(event);" onmousedown="ClearText();" /> 
            </div> 
      </form>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `true` in ClearText function:

```
function ClearText() { 
    if (document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value == "ALPHA-NUMBR") { 
        document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value = ""; 
    } 
    return true; 
}
```

Actually return false allows default action of the element. So in your case the field was not able to get the focus.

I'm not sure why it works in IE. I suppose it's a bug of this browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change keycode as which and also change onmousedown as onclick

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt; 
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>MRBN Textbox Sample</title> 
<style type="text/css"> 
.MRBN 
{ 
    width:145px; 
    font-family:Verdana; 
    font-size:12pt; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #EDEBEC; 
} 
</style> 
</head> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function ValidateText(evnt) {
            TxtLen = document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value.length; 
            document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").style.color = "#33CC33"; 
            if (TxtLen < 5) { 
                if ((((evnt.which > 64) && (evnt.which < 91)) || ((evnt.which > 96) && (evnt.which < 123))) != true) { 
                    alert("1st letter/1st name +1st 4/last name..."); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
            else if (TxtLen == 5) { 
                if (evnt.which != 45) { 
                    alert("This needs dash or hyphen here..."); 
                    return false; 
                } 
            } 
            else if ((TxtLen > 5) && (TxtLen < 11)) { 
                    if (((evnt.which > 47) && (evnt.which < 58)) != true) { 
                        alert("Put last 5 of your phone number..."); 
                        return false; 
                    } 
            } 
            else { 
                alert("5-5. Now give it to Riders & WIN...!"); 
                return false; 
            } 
        }

    function ClearText() { 
        if (document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value == "ALPHA-NUMBR") { 
            document.getElementById("TxtMRBN").value = ""; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
</script> 
<body> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <div> 
            <input type="text" id="TxtMRBN" class="MRBN" value="ALPHA-NUMBR" onkeypress="return ValidateText(event);" onclick="return ClearText();" /> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```